# bs4 почему возникает ошибка AttributeError при парсинге сайта с фильмами

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

При парсинге сайта более 100 позиций проходит, потом через 2-3 начинает выдавать ошибку, хотя все обьекты имеются на страницах

**Сайт: https://hd3.zetfix.online/films/new_netflix_films/**

**Ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valiev/code/python/parser_zetflix/main.py", line 53, in <module>
    film_name = soup.find(class_="fright fx-1").find("h1").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

**Пример кода:**

```
with open("film_url_list.text") as file:

lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

data_dist = []
count = 0

for line in lines:
    q = requests.get(line)
    result = q.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(result, "lxml")
    film_name = soup.find(class_="fright fx-1").find("h1").text
    film_info = soup.find(class_="finfo").text

    data_film = {
        "name": film_name,
        "info": film_info
    }

    count += 1
    # sleep(random.randrange(2, 4))
    print(f"#{count}: {line} is done!")
    data_dist.append(data_film)


    with open("data_film.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(data_dist, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140243/discussion-on-question-by---bs4----attribute).

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'Referer': 'https://hd3.zetfix.online/films/new_netflix_films/page/14/'}
response = requests.get('https://hd3.zetfix.online/films/vyshka/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
film_name = soup.find(class_="fright fx-1").find("h1").text
print(film_name)

Вышка смотреть онлайн
```

Если удалить headers в запросе будеть ошибка

```
response = requests.get('https://hd3.zetfix.online/films/vyshka/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
film_name = soup.find(class_="fright fx-1").find("h1").text
print(film_name)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```